# Unique PayPal IPN variable for buyer and seller

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I've been working on a website where people can submit questions to me online and I'll answer them for a small fee. I'm using PayPal to collect this small fee, and I've recently successfully implemented the PayPal IPN in order to collect transaction IDs. What I planned on doing was storing the transaction ID and asking the individual for the transaction ID when they ask a question. Once a transaction ID had a question associated with it, it would be marked as used and could not be used twice. I chose this method over having people create an account and storing variables within each account because I figure people will be deterred from using my service (it's related to academia) so this is kind of perfect.

**So.. what's the issue?**

I had a friend try it out, and we unfortunately found out that the transaction ID that I got *and stored* is different from the transaction ID that he got, hence completely breaking the system I had envisioned.

**My Question**

What is a unique variable passed on through the PayPal IPN that I can use to ask the buyer about and ensure that it doesn't get used twice?

I want the process to be automated, which eliminates the possibility of invoices since you have to do those by hand each time.

Thanks for your thoughts and efforts.

Comment: How are you getting the transaction ID??  You should be getting it with:  `$_POST['txn_id']`, than you should store it in the database.  I use it to append it to the actual URL (after applying an `md5()` to it with the current time pattern) and this gives me a unique value (stored in the db) that I than use to attach to the URL that gets emailed to the paypal user account, using `$_POST['receiver_email']`.

Comment: @SolomonClosson I am retrieving it in the same manor that you are. I like that idea, but how do you ensure that someone doesn't just reuse that URL?

Comment: You can place a column in there `views`, everytime that url is accessed, increment the `views` database column.  Or you can call the column `locked`, when it is accessed, change it from 0 to 1.  Than in the script if the column, `locked` or `views` (whatever you decide to call it) equals 1, than don't allow access.  Should be `TINYINT(2)` db column.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `custom` in your PayPal integration, which is subsequently returned in the IPN message.

I.e., for Express Checkout:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout  
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.00  
RETURNURL=http://...  
CUSTOM=yourUniqueDataHere
```

Or for Payments Standard:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="yourUniqueDataHere">
```

Once the transaction completes, you can find `custom` in your IPN message's POST data.